issue writing a 5 million row sparse matrix to s3
This is my function:
def write_sparse_matrix_to_s3(matrix, bucket_name, key, header=None):
    """
    Writes a sparse matrix in Compressed Sparse Row (CSR) format to an S3 bucket.
    
    Args:
        matrix (scipy.sparse.csr_matrix): The sparse matrix to be written.
        bucket_name (str): The name of the S3 bucket to write the matrix to.
        key (str): The key (file name) to use for the object in S3.
        header (list, optional): A list of strings representing the header information to be saved with the matrix.
    """
    s3 = boto3.client('s3')
    
    # Save the matrix data to a BytesIO object
    matrix_data = io.BytesIO()
    np.savez(matrix_data, data=matrix.data, indices=matrix.indices, indptr=matrix.indptr, shape=matrix.shape)
    
    # Prepare the header information
    if header is not None:
        header_data = '\n'.join(header).encode('utf-8')
        matrix_data.seek(0)
        matrix_data = header_data + b'\n' + matrix_data.read()
    
    # Upload the file to S3
    s3.put_object(Bucket=bucket_name, Key=key, Body=matrix_data.getvalue())
    
    print(f"Sparse matrix saved to s3://{bucket_name}/{key}")

However when i run it on a large data i get this error - ClientError: An error occurred (EntityTooLarge) when calling the PutObject operation: Your proposed upload exceeds the maximum allowed size
Need help on writing a function to write large CSR files to S3 and read back from S3

This error occurs when the object being uploaded to S3 is too large. If a single PUT operation is being used by the AWS SDKs, REST API, or AWS CLI, you can upload a single object up to 5 GB in size.
Uploading objects - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/upload-objects.html
To upload objects larger than 5 GB in size, you can use multipart upload, with multipart upload you can upload a single large object up to 5 TB in size.
Uploading and copying objects using multipart upload - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/mpuoverview.html
you need all of these permissions to use upload_file:
"Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "s3:AbortMultipartUpload",
        "s3:DeleteObject",
        "s3:ListMultipartUploadParts",
        "s3:PutObject",
        "s3:GetObject"

In your code, put_object will send it all in one put with a 5GB limit. Rather, using upload_file will do "multipart" uploads if necessary and calls a callback function when done. You will have to use something like below code
def write_sparse_matrix_to_s3(matrix, bucket_name, key, header=None):
"""
Writes a sparse matrix in Compressed Sparse Row (CSR) format to an S3 bucket using multipart upload.

Args:
    matrix (scipy.sparse.csr_matrix): The sparse matrix to be written.
    bucket_name (str): The name of the S3 bucket to write the matrix to.
    key (str): The key (file name) to use for the object in S3.
    header (list, optional): A list of strings representing the header information to be saved with the matrix.
"""
s3 = boto3.client('s3')

# Save the matrix data to a temporary file
with tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(delete=False) as temp_file:
    np.savez(temp_file, data=matrix.data, indices=matrix.indices, indptr=matrix.indptr, shape=matrix.shape)
    
    # Prepare the header information (if provided)
    if header is not None:
        header_data = '\n'.join(header).encode('utf-8')
        with open(temp_file.name, 'rb+') as f:
            existing_data = f.read()
            f.seek(0)
            f.write(header_data + b'\n' + existing_data)
    
    # Configure transfer with multipart threshold
    config = TransferConfig(multipart_threshold=5 * 1024 * 1024)  # 5MB threshold

    # Upload the file to S3 using multipart upload
    s3.upload_file(temp_file.name, bucket_name, key, Config=config)
    
# Delete the temporary file
os.remove(temp_file.name)

print(f"Sparse matrix saved to s3://{bucket_name}/{key}")

